Single threaded process unable to saturate disk read capacity
I'm on a VMWare backed VM with a disk connected using virtual SCSI connector.
I'm observing a prblem I never saw on any other system. A simple signle process application isn't able to read a file at the full speed of the underlying sotrage device.
I managed to track down the issue to the difference between 2 fio commands:
With:
fio --name=read_throughput --directory=. --numjobs=1 --size=10G --time_based --runtime=60s --ramp_time=2s --direct=0 --verify=0 --bs=64K --iodepth=64 --rw=read --group_reporting=1
I'm getting only a very low read throughput:
READ: bw=529MiB/s (554MB/s), 529MiB/s-529MiB/s (554MB/s-554MB/s), io=30.0GiB (33.3GB), run=60001-60001msec
But with multiple processes I'm able to reach nearly the maximum speed of the underlying storage system as expected:
fio --name=read_throughput --directory=. --numjobs=8 --size=10G --time_based --runtime=60s --ramp_time=2s --direct=0 --verify=0 --bs=64K --iodepth=64 --rw=read --g roup_reporting=1
READ: bw=3238MiB/s (3395MB/s), 3238MiB/s-3238MiB/s (3395MB/s-3395MB/s), io=190GiB (204GB), run=60001-60001msec
I checked the settings that in my opinion could have an impact on such behavior but I don't see anyting problematic:
# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
[mq-deadline] none

# cat /sys/block/sda/device/queue_depth
254

The only one that could be problematic was:
# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational
1

I forced it to 0 but the results of the single thread fio test were the same.
I checked the RAM and CPU during the single threaded fio test and the VM is definitely not nor RAM nor CPU bound.
As a reference this is what I'm getting on my personal pretty average laptop with a standard m2 SSD:
fio --name=read_throughput --directory=. --numjobs=1 --size=1G --time_based --runtime=60s --ramp_time=2s --direct=0 --verify=0 --bs=64K --iodepth=64 --rw=read --group_reporting=1

READ: bw=2003MiB/s (2101MB/s), 2003MiB/s-2003MiB/s (2101MB/s-2101MB/s), io=117GiB (126GB), run=60001-60001msec

fio --name=read_throughput --directory=. --numjobs=8 --size=1G --time_based --runtime=60s --ramp_time=2s --direct=0 --verify=0 --bs=64K --iodepth=64 --rw=read --group_reporting=1

READ: bw=2277MiB/s (2387MB/s), 2277MiB/s-2277MiB/s (2387MB/s-2387MB/s), io=133GiB (143GB), run=60038-60038msec

Any ideas on how to move forward?

There's an excellent writeup in the answer here about measuring fio read performance https://askubuntu.com/a/991311/883853 and the other answers in that question to help you narrow down the reason. It largely depends on the actual physical storage device (Enterprise SSDs often require high concurrency to hit top speeds for example). Other factors like latency can affect single vs multithread performance differently, but not usually by x4 like you're seeing.

random thought but maybe unrelated: https://serverfault.com/questions/923487/what-does-iodepth-in-fio-tests-really-mean-is-it-the-queue-depth

@Cpt.Whale I edited my question adding as a reference the same test run on my laptop. The difference between numjobs=1 and numjobs=8 is much more in line with what I would have expected.

Is the VM also running on the laptop, or what kind of storage does it have? Are your findings still true if you set direct=1, iodepth=1, or both?

No the VM is running on the client's ESXi cluster (2 nodes) both connected to the storage bay using 2 direct Fibre Channel links. The storage bay is a "Dell emc powervault me4024". The 3.2GB/s speed I'm observing with numjobs=8 is the maximum speed of the 2 FC connections. With numjobs=1 when 1 set direct=1 the speed goes as low as 200MB/s. If I add ioengine=libaio when direct=0 I get back my ~500MB/s speed. iodepth=1 doesn't seem to have any effect no matter the other options in my case.

Do you see similar behavior on other VMs/Guest OS? If so, there are tons of configs and stats to look at on the host/san as well. Latency is probably the biggest factor imo for single-thread performance, but only the host knows the real values (watch with esxtop for example). Take a look through https://www.codyhosterman.com/2017/02/understanding-vmware-esxi-queuing-and-the-flasharray/, it's got some good troubleshooting steps to get more information, even if the actual cause is different
